# Issues when using SSIS Execute SQL Task to insert a row into SQL Server with multiple parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use SSIS to insert a row with multiple parameters but I get this error :

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "insert into ids (id,sqljobname,ojobname,ojobstartd..." failed with the following error: "The statement has been terminated.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

This is how I set up the Execute SQL Task:

```
insert into ids (id, sqljobname, ojobname, ojobstartdate)
values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

[image]

Please let me know where I set it up wrong. I don't think the ParentJobStartDate is an issue because I set it up with string.

Comment: I'm not sure how does it work, but you might miss the apostrophies in param values(?,'?','?','?'). Try to profile the query, it might give you an idea what was wrong.

Comment: Can you check the connection, if it is set properly? Also, check the size of the strings you have as params - maybe it's bigger than 100?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys, everything I did was correct. I just made a mistake when creating the table in sql server. I created the table like this:

```
create table ids
(id int,
sqljobname nvarchar(255),
ojobname nvarchar(255),
ojobstartdate nvarchar(255),
sqljobstartdate datetime )
```

So the columns will only have 1 for the size and make the insert failed. I have already fixed it.